APK with storage issue
I am trying to get image path from user device through file picker, store the path information in client.storage file for later use, and to use this image as an ElevatedButton. While this is working on Windows, it is not the case on Android.
I built the APK with the following command: flet build apk --include-packages flet_permission_handler -vv
Code sample:
import flet as ft
import os


def get_folder(page, base_path):
    store = {}
    image_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']
    for item in os.listdir(base_path):        
        item_path = os.path.join(base_path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(item_path) and any(item.lower().endswith(ext) for ext in image_extensions):
            tmp = page.client_storage.get("lib")
            page.client_storage.set("lib", page.client_storage.get("lib") + [item_path])    
            print(page.client_storage.get("lib"))
            page.update()
            break

def build_home(page):
    imagesPath = page.client_storage.get("lib")
    images = ft.ResponsiveRow()
    for item in imagesPath:
        images.controls.append(
            ft.ElevatedButton(
                col={"sm": 12, "md": 4, "xl": 2},
                content=ft.Image(
                    src=item,
                    border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(20)
                ),
                style=ft.ButtonStyle(
                    shape={ft.MaterialState.DEFAULT: ft.RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=20)},
                    padding={ft.MaterialState.HOVERED: 0}
                )
            )
        )
    
    page.update()
    return images

def main(page: ft.Page):
    if page.client_storage.contains_key("lib"):
        print("storage exists")
        print(page.client_storage.get("lib"))
    else:
        page.client_storage.set("lib", [])

    # PermissionHandler ------------------------------------------------
    ph = ft.PermissionHandler()  
    page.overlay.append(ph)  
    
    def request_permission_media(e=None):
        try:
            result = ph.request_permission(ft.PermissionType.MEDIA_LIBRARY)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Media Library Permission Error: {ex}")

    def request_permission_external_storage(e=None):
        try:
            result = ph.request_permission(ft.PermissionType.STORAGE)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Storage Permission Error: {ex}")

    # DATA path--------------------------------------------
    page.storage = list(page.client_storage.get_keys("lib"))

    ## Home page--------------------------------------------
    if len(page.storage) > 0:
        home = build_home(page)
        home.visible = True
    else:
        home = ft.ResponsiveRow()

    ### Folder picker --------------------------------------
    def pick_files_result(result: ft.FilePickerResultEvent):
        if result.path:   
            get_folder(page, result.path) 
            page.resultPath = result.path
            page.storage = page.client_storage.get_keys("key-prefix.")
            page.controls[0] = build_home(page)
            page.update()

    page.pick_files_dialog = ft.FilePicker(on_result=pick_files_result)

    page.overlay.append(page.pick_files_dialog)

    # Build pages--------------------------------------------
    #page.add(page.home)#, page.chapters)
    page.floating_action_button = ft.FloatingActionButton(
        icon=ft.icons.ADD,
        tooltip="Add a story",
        shape=ft.CircleBorder(),
        width=100,
        mini=True,
        on_click = lambda _: page.pick_files_dialog.get_directory_path()
    )    


    page.add(home) # page.controls[0]
    page.update()

ft.app(target=main, upload_dir="assets")

If I run this on Windows and pick a folder where an image ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'] is present, I get the ElevatedButton created with the image within the folder. However, on Android nothing happens.

You will need to handle file paths differently for Android + ensure you have the proper permissions. Make sure you have an assets directory in your project.
I have slightly modified your version to work on both:
import flet as ft
import os
from pathlib import Path

def get_folder(page, base_path):
    """Fetch image files from the specified folder and store paths."""
    image_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']
    
    try:
        if not base_path:
            print("Base path not provided.")
            return

        path = Path(base_path) if isinstance(base_path, str) else base_path

        # Handle Android content URIs
        if str(path).startswith('content://'):
            android_path = str(path)
            existing_paths = page.client_storage.get("lib") or []
            if android_path not in existing_paths:
                existing_paths.append(android_path)
                page.client_storage.set("lib", existing_paths)
                print(f"Added Android path: {android_path}")
        else:
            # Handle normal filesystem paths
            for item in os.listdir(path):
                item_path = os.path.join(str(path), item)
                if os.path.isfile(item_path) and item.lower().endswith(tuple(image_extensions)):
                    existing_paths = page.client_storage.get("lib") or []
                    if item_path not in existing_paths:
                        existing_paths.append(item_path)
                        page.client_storage.set("lib", existing_paths)
                        print(f"Added path: {item_path}")
            print(f"Current storage: {page.client_storage.get('lib')}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in get_folder: {e}")

def build_home(page):
    """Build the home page UI with stored images."""
    try:
        images = ft.ResponsiveRow()
        images_path = page.client_storage.get("lib") or []

        for img_path in images_path:
            img_src = img_path
            images.controls.append(
                ft.ElevatedButton(
                    content=ft.Image(
                        src=img_src,
                        border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(20),
                        fit=ft.ImageFit.COVER,
                    ),
                    style=ft.ButtonStyle(
                        shape=ft.RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=20),
                        padding=0,
                    ),
                )
            )
        return images
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in build_home: {e}")
        return ft.ResponsiveRow()

def main(page: ft.Page):
    # Initialize client storage
    if not page.client_storage.contains_key("lib"):
        page.client_storage.set("lib", [])

    def request_permissions():
        try:
            ph = ft.PermissionHandler()
            ph.request_permission(ft.PermissionType.MEDIA_LIBRARY)
            ph.request_permission(ft.PermissionType.STORAGE)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Permission Error: {ex}")

    request_permissions()

    def on_file_picker_result(e: ft.FilePickerResultEvent):
        if e.path:
            get_folder(page, e.path)
            page.controls[0] = build_home(page)
            page.update()

    file_picker = ft.FilePicker(
        on_result=on_file_picker_result,
        allow_multiple=False,
        allow_folders=True
    )
    page.overlay.append(file_picker)

    def show_file_picker(e):
        if ft.platform.is_android:
            file_picker.pick_files(allowed_extensions=['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'])
        else:
            file_picker.get_directory_path()

    page.floating_action_button = ft.FloatingActionButton(
        icon=ft.icons.ADD,
        tooltip="Add a story",
        shape=ft.CircleBorder(),
        mini=True,
        on_click=show_file_picker
    )

    # Initial page setup
    home_ui = build_home(page)
    page.add(home_ui)
    page.update()

ft.app(
    target=main,
    upload_dir="assets",
    assets_dir="assets"
)

You need the permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Build the APK with the required permissions:
flet build apk --include-packages flet_permission_handler,flet_core -vv

Hope this helps. It should work on Windows and Android now.
